# Using NPM, node.js and discord.js, I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a discord bot using NPM and discord.js, but I keep getting an error which says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null".

Here's my bot code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'ඞ amogus ඞ' }, status: 'online' });


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `${prefix}ping`) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}beep`) {
        message.channel.send('Boop.');
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}server`) {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}smile`) {
        message.react('');
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}ree`) {
        message.channel.send(`REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE`)
    } else if (message.content === `among us`) {
    message.channel.send(`AMOG US??? ඞඞඞඞඞ`)
    } else if (message.content === `amongus`) {
    message.channel.send(`did you say AMOG US?????? ඞඞඞ`)
    } else if (message.content === `amogus`) {
    message.channel.send(`wow.. are u talking about MOGUS? ඞඞඞ`)
    } else if (message.content === `shut up`) {
    message.channel.send(`no u XD HAHAHAHAHA seriously though no you shut up`)
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}stop`) {
    message.channel.send(`no ;-;`)
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}frog`) {
        message.react('');
    } else if (message.content === `poo`) {
    message.channel.send(`are you talking about yourself?`)
    } else if (message.content === `shit`) {
    message.channel.send(`are you talking about yourself?`)
    } else if (message.content === `doo doo doo doo`) {
    message.channel.send(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQR_n90iWi0`)
    } else if (message.content === `ha`) {
    message.channel.send(`I don't get the joke.`)
    }
});


client.login(token);
```

and here's the error:

```
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cassnorland/index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

The bot worked perfectly before this, I hadn't had any errors previously (apart from typos)

I have tried setActivity as well, but same problem.

I don't know what versions of software I'm using, sorry.

Comment: The error means that `client.user` is `null`.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to move the line to a place where `client.user` is no longer `null`. Try moving it immediately before or after `console.log('Ready!');` (inside the 'ready' callback function)

Comment: @ChrisG I put it immediately after and that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: you need to login first before access user.

Answer (score 1):

`client.user` is `null` since the bot user is not yet logged in. Move the `client.user.setPresence` call inside the `ready` event handler.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
  client.user.setPresence({
    activity: { name: 'ඞ amogus ඞ' },
    status: 'online',
  })
})
```